# can sessions be shared for cross doman single sign on in php

Tags: php, session

Please let me know the procedure to share the sessions between two domains or the best way to implement single sign on in php for cross domain.

Comment: Whoa whoa! Entire *books* could be written on this topic...could you narrow it down a bit? In the meantime, see e.g. this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389175/kerberos-authentification-in-php

Comment: just refer these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064243/php-sessions-across-sub-domains and http://www.gonnalearn.com/2008/04/10/sharing-session-data-across-domains-with-php/  also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759312/session-share-across-multiple-domains-on-same-server

Comment: It's not entirely clear in your question to what you refer to a) to share sessions across hosts or b) the best way to implement single sign on in PHP - That are two different things. Additionally this relates highly to server configuration so you should tell what you've tried so far and into which concrete problem you did run.

Answer (score 0):

The SSO solution with CURL. Check below link.

[PHP + MySQL + cURL: Single Sign On With Multiple Domains](http://rashidi.zin.my/geek-talks/2009/06/30/php-mysql-curl-single-sign-on-with-multiple-domains.html)