# How to auto login a website using windows authentication on intranet?

Tags: php, html, ldap

I am hosting my site on `xampp` and want to auto login my website using `LDAP`. So as of now I use `PHP` to grab the windows current username and try to validate it with AD via ldap and it works.

But since PHP is server sided it only grabs current user of the system in which `xampp` is running how can I achieve it for every system connected via LAN. If I run it on any other system of intranet it shows the system's name which has `xampp` running on it.

Is there any way to grab windows current user details on the client side or is there any better and easy way for auto login.

Answer (score 0):

Using the workstation-provided logon name is quite insecure -- there are ways to essentially spoof the logon information. When you trust the workstation's USERNAME value, you don't have any way to differentiate between "lisa logged into *her* domain named example.com" and "lisa logged into the official company domain named example.com". Possibly even "lisa logged into her computer in the workgroup she happened to name example.com".

Assuming you want users to be able to authenticate without having to enter their credentials, the secure path would be either to use federated authentication or the Kerberos token. If you have ADFS set up, federation auth can be acheived in [PHP with Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/php). If the web server can communicate with the domain controllers, the web server can use Kerberos tokens and use the *server* version of the logged on username. See, as an example, [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389175/kerberos-authentication-in-php).

Either way, users with existing Windows logons are able to authenticate to the website without typing credentials. Users who *don't* have existing Windows logons get prompted for creds.