# SSO in PHP application using AD credentials independent of Web Server

Tags: php, active-directory, kerberos, ntlm, domaincontroller

I have a PHP application running with Nginx on a Linux server and it has a successful integration with my Active Directory using [LDAP](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.ldap.php).

In the current scenario, the user is able to create a new login for the app or use his Windows credentials to log into the application.

Now, I'm trying to implement a complete Single-Sign On (SSO) and the user logged with his credentials in the Windows machine in the domain will be able to open the app logged without use the credentials again.

Doing some research on it, since my Linux server are not in the same domain, the best options is use NTLM (old and insecure), [Kerberos protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecAuthN/microsoft-kerberos) or [Negotiate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecAuthN/microsoft-negotiate) protocol (that will choose among NTLM and Kerberos for each request), depending on Windows version and what is implemented in the Domain Controller.

There is a lot of tutorials in the internet and also some [good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389175/kerberos-authentication-in-php) [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257024/apache2-php-sso-with-active-directory) on the theme here in SO. This another [link](https://github.com/Rich2k/adLDAP/wiki/Seamless-authentication) shows a good overview about the options using Apache as web server (for Kerberos option, I found a [Nginx port](https://devhub.io/repos/bcandrea-spnego-http-auth-nginx-module), so this is not the main problem).

Well, I created some test application using these approaches (including all changes in the [browser side](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Integrated_authentication), limited to Firefox), but all of then are dependents of Web Server (Apache, Nginx or even IIS). Since My app already has a complete integration with AD through LDAP, I'm interested in some Web Server independent solution. Are there any way to "bypass" the authentication in Web Server and get the information about the logged user direct on my PHP code (Client (Firefox) to Server (PHP))?

My best guesses for now are some type of "pure" PHP implementation of [Kerberos](http://mbechler.eenterphace.org/blog/index.php?/archives/6-Doing-GSSNegotiate-SSO-using-Mozilla-Firefox,-MIT-Kerberos-and-PHP.html), that needs of a PECL module or [NTLM](https://loune.net/2007/10/simple-lightweight-ntlm-in-php/), that is insecure and still asks for the user credentials in the first request.

I know that maybe its impossible, but I'm asking it for the case that I missed something important information in this research. Is it possible to get the windows user info direct in PHP?

Comment: If you want to get the 'windows user' via SSO then SPNEGO protocol is the way to go. So you need some component which validates the Kerberos Service Token sent to your app via SPNEGO. It's quite interesting that there are not many PHP-extesions/modules available to achieve this.

Comment: I did a lot of research on the subject, but didn't found any PHP solution that is totally independent of WebServer

Comment: I dont believe this is theoretically possible, since php will always stand behind a web server. That is, php will only get information that the web server will pass onto it. Obviously, you cant get that information (which is found strictly on the client) in any way from php. The browser configuration is the first step, because he needs to pass the data, and the Web server needs to be configured to accept it. I'm basically looking for the same thing you do currently, with zero prior experience to AD, so this is just my opinion gathered from 3 hour research.

Comment: Also, the best solution for you is probably http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html

Answer (score 1):

If you don't insist on nginx use Apache Web Server 2.4 with `mod_auth_gssapi` this is great, high quality code written by people who know what they do. I have been doing this for years for my PHP stuff.

Comment: I'm trying to find some solution that is web server agnostic (if it exists), but it's good to know that Apache has this another option. It looks like a solution more easy to go than mod_auth_kerb.

Comment: mod_auth_kerb is dead, don't use it. Solving it in PHP means doing C calls to MIT Kerberos. So, why bother use that module and be happy.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleSAMLphp

https://simplesamlphp.org/

> SimpleSAMLphp is an application written in native PHP that deals with authentication. The main focus of SimpleSAMLphp is providing support for:
>
> SAML 2.0 as a Service Provider (SP)
> SAML 2.0 as an Identity Provider (IdP)
> However, it also supports many other identity protocols and frameworks, such as CAS, OpenID Connect, WS-Federation and OAuth, and is easily extendable, so you can develop your own modules if you like.
>
> The community-led project has a large user base, a helpful user community and a diverse set of external contributors.